# Recursive replaceAll java

Tags: java, regex, recursion

I am trying to replace all the repeated characters from a String in Java, and let only one.

For example:

`aaaaa` ---> `a`

For that, I have tried using the `replaceAll` method:

```
"aaaaa".replaceAll("a*","a") //returns "aa"
```

I have developed a recursive method, which is probably not very efficient:

```
public String recursiveReplaceAll(String original,String regex, String replacement) {
    if (original.equals(original.replaceAll(regex, replacement))) return original;
    return recursiveReplaceAll(original.replaceAll(regex, replacement),regex,replacement);
}
```

This method works, I was just wondering if there was anything using RegEx for example, which does the work with better performance.

Comment: `replaceAll("a+", "a")`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `replaceAll` approach was nearly right - it's just that `*` matches 0 occurrences. You want `+` to mean "one or more".

```
"aaaaa".replaceAll("a+","a") // Returns "a"
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do it without recursion. The regular expression `"(.)\\1+"` will [capture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) every character followed by themselves [at least once](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html), and it replaces them with the captured character. Thus, this removes any repeated characters.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "aaaabbbaaa";
    String result = str.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
    System.out.println(result); // prints "aba".
}
```

With this, it works for all characters.